# How to draw a circle on a gnuplot figure?

Tags: gnuplot

Basically I have a figure below, which is drawn by `gnu plot`.

[image]

The code is listed as follows:

```
set term pdf size 2.8,1.4 font "Arial,08"
set output "plot/application.pdf"
set datafile separator ","
set offset 0, 0, 0, 0
set size ratio 0.5
set xtics norangelimit
set ytics nomirror
set termoption dashed
 set ylabel "Binary Similarity (%)"
set xlabel "Iteration"
set yrange [0:110]
set style data linespoints
set key vertical maxrows 5
set key top right
set key vertical maxrows 5

set style line 2 lt 1 lc rgb "skyblue" lw 1
set style arrow 8 heads size screen 0.008,90 ls 2 lw 10
set arrow from 9.0,0 to 9.0,40 nohead lw 1 as 8

plot 'plot/application.csv' using 1:xtic((int($0)%4)==0?sprintf("%d", $0*10):"") title columnheader(1) pt 1 lw 1, \
'' using 2 title columnheader(2) pt 2 lw 1 ps .1 lc rgb "#4169E1", \
'' using 3 title columnheader(3) pt 3 lw 1 ps .1 lc rgb "#DAA520", \
'' using 4 title columnheader(4) pt 4 lw 1 ps .1 lc 5, \
'' using 5 title columnheader(5) pt 4 lw 1 ps .1 lc 9, \
'' using 6 title columnheader(6) pt 4 lw 1 ps .1 lc 7, \
'' using 7 title columnheader(7) pt 5 lw 1 ps .1 lc 8, \
'' using 7 title columnheader(8) pt 5 lw 1 ps .1 lc 9
```

I basically want to highlight datas at `90`, and that's why I draw a blue arrow line there.. But as you can see, it looks awkward...

So I am thinking to change the blue line into a red circle, something like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do that? Note that it even has an associated legend of the red circle.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can always add

```
'< echo 90 20 10' w circ
```

to the plot.

Comment: Thank you for your rely. But.. any command to adjust the size and color? I just cannot google it... sorry

Comment: @computereasy: Size is the third number. To change the color, use `lc 7` (`linecolor`) or similar.